# LoadError in AuthorSessionsController#destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I am working on a Rails tutorial and trying to create authentication using the gem Sorcery.

I'm getting the error LoadError in `AuthorSessionsController#destroy` when I try to visit `/login`

It tells me:

```
Unable to autoload constant AuthorSessionsController, expected /home/cabox/workspace/blogger/app/controllers/author_sessions_controller.rb to define it
```

I'm not sure what to post here to get help, very new to Rails and Stack Overflow.

I do have a git repository with all of the code, it can be found at:

[bitbucket repo link](https://bitbucket.org/davidtaylorjr/blogger/overview) please checkout to authentication branch.

The instructions for the tutorial I am following can be found at

[tutorial link](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i5:-authentication)

Any help is appreciated. If you need anymore info or if there is a better way to post the question please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a case of messed up naming convention. Please follow this steps.

1. Remove `app/controllers/authorsessions_controller.rb` file because you already have `app/controllers/author_sessions_controller.rb` file.
2. As per Rails naming convention class names should be in `CamelCase`. In your scenario, the class name should be `AuthorSessionsController` in `app/controllers/author_sessions_controller.rb`.